# Lazy loaded DLLs

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2

Is there a way to lazy load DLLs in webpack?

I have been looking at the following example: https://gist.github.com/robertknight/058a194f45e77ff95fcd

The example separates out a bundle as a `DLL`, but includes it via script tag.

Is there way to tell Webpack to conditionally include the `DLL` from another bundle instead?

The idea is to use it as a lazy loading technique where the bundle is only loaded if some user specific runtime condition is true.

For context I am doing this in Angular 2

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [code splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) rather than the DLL plugin -- I think the DLL plugin was born out of a need to optimise compile times more than anything.

Code splitting will split out your bundle into multiple chunks which will automatically be fetched only when required.

> NOTE: Webpack 1 uses `require.ensure` and Webpack 2 uses `System.import` to define 'split points'.

Comment: This is true, but a reason to lazy load a DLL bundle is because it precomiles that bundle so you don't need to rebuild it every time you build the app. For example, if you want to lazy load a large library like `Kendo UI`, then `require.ensure` works fine for lazy loading, but webpack must rebuild it every time, losing the benefit of DLL bundles.

Comment: @TetraDev are you using Webpack in watch mode as I've found incremental builds to be very fast even with many third party libs?

Comment: Yes You are right, I am using webpack watch mode for incremental builds, it is much faster. I was just referring to the initial build time, mine is about 35s, incremental about 5s.